# Disk encryption with Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, system-installation, encryption

I am thinking of installing Lubuntu 14.04 on top of my current Ubuntu 14.04 installation.

I have (and for professional reasons, require) full-disk encryption, so I have been researching this before proceeding with the installation.

I have found [this mention of a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1241833), though in a previous release:

Can anyone tell me whether this has been rectified or whether it is still an issue? (If so, my plan is essentially thwarted.)

Comment: Whatever you do, I strongly recommend not using your production device for testing. The linked bug is using LUKS. Since the bug is still open, I suspect it still exists. You could try a different full disk encryption method, such as [TrueCrypt](httphttp://www.truecrypt.org/). There is a [community TrueCrypt installation article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrueCrypt).

Comment: It's essentially a new machine so (SSD longevity concerns aside) I can nuke it and re-nuke it almost to my heart's content. I'm a relative Linux novice so I've been fiddling around with my initial Ubuntu installation to the point that it has become rather grotty anyway. I'm not adverse to tossing it out and starting anew. But I'd like to have a hand-holding graphical installer while I do so... and the relative certainty that what I am trying to do is possible and that if it fails it is due to a mistake I have made and can correct, rather than an obscure and insurmountable bug.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend trying TrueCrypt. I've been using it with Windows for many years and never had an issue. The community installation article makes installation look fairly straightforward. The project is currently going through an [audit](http://istruecryptauditedyet.com) funded by an [Indiegogo campaign](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/the-truecrypt-audit), which most FOSS projects never undergo.

Comment: TrueCrypt is "discontinued" software i.e. is no longer supported. I strongly recommend using Veracrypt instead, which is a fork from TrueCrypt and incorporates various improvements in functionality and security. There's more information here:- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VeraCrypt

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problems installing Lunbuntu 17.04 with disk encryption under VirtualBox. My resolution:

- Temporarily increase the virtual machine memorty to 6Gb 
  (to prevent memory problems due to lack of swap space)
- Try Lubuntu without installing
- Start LXTerminal
- Disable swap space by issuing the command `sudo swapoff --all`
- Preinstall LVM by issuing the command `sudo apt-get install lvm2`
- run 'Install Lubuntu 17.04' from the desktop

In my specific case, I also could have opted to simply install the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack, and encrypt my entire Virtual machine...